# Java multithread variable visibility problem

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I am learning about volatile of Java and my code is like this.

```
public class Test {
    public static boolean flag = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(()->{
            while(flag){
                // System.out.println(flag);
            }
            System.out.println("end");
        });
        t1.start();

        Thread.sleep(100);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(()->{
            flag = false;
            System.out.println("changed");
        });
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

I know if **flag** doesn't have volatile, the thread would not exist. It's a visibility problem.

However if I write some code in the while loop, like `System.out.println("abc")`, **t1** thread will read the new value and stop the loop.

I know how to use volatile to resolve the visibility problem, so my question is:

Why **t1** can read the new value of **flag** when I write `System.out.println("abc")` in the while loop?

Comment: **tl;dr** from the duplicate: `System.out.println()` is "special" because it involves synchronization which in many (all?) JVMs has the effect of a very broad read barrier and effectively causes the variable to be re-read from main memory. That is not required by the spec, but is a widely shared implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
while(flag){
     // System.out.println(flag);
}
```

you will have loop with an empty body, which can result in what is know by *Spin on field*; from [source](https://lgtm.com/rules/7850081/) one can read:

> Repeatedly reading a non-volatile field within the condition of an
> empty loop statement may result in an infinite loop, since a compiler
> optimization may move this field access out of the loop.

However, by adding a statement `System.out.println(flag);` to your loop you avoid the *Spin on field*. Notwithstanding, if thread `t1` read the field `flag` from its cache with a value `true`, the thread will only stop when the cache line that stores that field value gets invalidated, and the thread gets the new update valued `flag` field (*i.e.,* `flag=false`) from the main memory.

The `volatile` ensures, among others, that the threads will read the most update value the `flag` field. Hence, making the field `flag` `volatile` ensure that:

```
  while(flag){
    // System.out.println(flag);
}
```

potential compiler optimizations will NOT move the access to the field `flag` out of the loop.

> But if I write some code in the while loop, like
> System.out.println("abc"), thread t1 will read new value and stop
> loop.

This is two-folded first by adding the `System.out.println("abc")` you will avoid the *Spin on field* problem and second if one looks at the System.out.println code:

```
   public void println(String x) {
        synchronized (this) {
            print(x);
            newLine();
        }
    }
```

you can see that there is a `synchronized` being called, which will increase the likelihood that the thread will be reading the field `flag` not from the cache but from the main memory.